# Proper way to remove an old driver from %systemroot%\system32\drivers

Tags: windows, drivers, system32

Recently I was trying to find why out Windows 10 updates were failing on my computer. The [Driver Verifier](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/driver-verifier-tracking-down-a-mis-behaving/f5cb4faf-556b-4b6d-95b3-c48669e4c983) utility indicated a problem with `dcrypt.sys`, a file that had been left in `%systemroot%\system32\drivers` even after I had uninstalled DiskCryptor several years ago.

I made the mistake of deleting `dcrypt.sys` myself, but when I did that, Windows stopped loading. My inference is that, despite its being third party software, its presence was somehow required by the Windows startup sequence. (I ended up solving this by reinstalling Windows completely.)

What would have been the proper way to get rid of such a file?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you prefer a GUI method, use Microsoft's [Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns). It requires no installation. Simply run it elevated, then navigate to the Drivers tab, clear the checkmark next to the driver you wish to disable, then reboot the computer:

[image]

Not only is this a simple way to enable/disable drivers and services (along with pretty much anything else that starts automatically in Windows), but it's very easy to ***undo*** changes if you find they have unwanted consequences or you're simply experimenting with your configuration.

By the way, the next time you disable a critical startup item and Windows will not boot, try using System Restore. It is capable of restoring the driver file you deleted as well as any Registry settings you might change (including changed made by Autoruns) in an effort to disable it.

Windows automatically creates Restore Points when certain critical actions are about to be taken (such as before installing Updates), but it's a good idea to [create one manually](https://superuser.com/a/1022811/213131) before making changes to important startup items. And if your system fails to boot and you need to use a Restore Point, here are [directions](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/windows-10-advanced-startup-options-menu) on how to do that.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently /enum-drivers is a windows 10 option and not windows 7 or 8.1

In Windows 7 and 8.1 its just **-e** not --enum-drivers

From and administrative command prompt:

```
pnputil /enum-drivers
```

Find the driver on the list, get the name of the INF file.

```
pnputil /delete-driver oem0.inf
```

Windows 7,8.1

```
pnputil -d oem0.inf
```

change oem0.inf to whatever you discovered windows named it in the step above.

If windows was broken and didn't start.

Boot off the windows install media

Use F10 (or maybe F8) to get to a command prompt

do a dir command on each letter until you find the windows folder.

dir c:
dir d:
dir e:
....

Find the offending driver.

```
dism /image:d:\ /Get-Drivers
```

replace something.inf with the offending driver name.

```
dism /image:d:\ /remove-driver /driver:something.inf
```

Comment: you can test it yourself http://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms - in the meantime please update to reflect that this is windows 10 only - as it doesnt work on windows 8.1 either

Comment: @StevenPenny  updated answer based on results from a Windows 7 vm.

Answer (score 2):

Start regedit. In the left pane, navigate to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services
```

Now look for a subkey under services called `dcrypt`.

- If it’s not there, look for something of a similar name, like `dskcrypt`.
- If you still can’t find it, use regedit’s Find command to search for `dcrypt.sys` in 
  a subkey under `Services`. The string `dcrypt.sys` should be in a value called
  `ImagePath`.

When you find the key, navigate to it and check that you do indeed see
`ImagePath:` `...dcrypt.sys` in the right pane. Now double-click the value
called `Start` and change it to `4`, which means Disabled.

That should do it.